# Node mongodb search

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How can I search mongodb by username ? I have database with unique usernames, but I want when I enter search query to get a list of all usernames that contains similar characters. For example if I search for 'name' that I get 'name1' , 'name_1', 'name2' etc.
Here is my code:

```
router.post('/search', (req, res, next) => {

   User.find({username: req.body.username})
    .then(user => {
       if(user){
         res.json({user});
       }else {
         return res.json({success: false, message: 'User not found'});
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular expressions in queries, thats means that queried field values can also be matched with regular a expression. For example: `{ username: /^name/}` In this case will search all usernames that starts with name, but you can play with teh regular expression.

For more information: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html

Answer (score 0):

Try regular expresion:

```
User.find({"username": /.*name.*/})
```

Answer (score 0):

A few ways:

1. Regex, as mentioned:

   User.find({ username: /name/i });
2. $where:

   User.find({ $where: { "username.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) > -1" }});

Mind that this is both very slow, especially if you have a lot of users, as those operations won't use indexes. You could get a bit of help there if you use regex with a prefix (start-of-word), e.g.

```
User.find({ username: /^name/ });
```